# How do that list return values and keys in django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I want get  stage.name

```
My structure  list
    '''   'stages' : [{
                    'stage' : {
                            'name': "@!#2",
                           }
                 }]
    '''
```

I tried in templates

```
template.html '''
    {% for  key in stages %}
        <p>{{ key }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    '''
```

And how you see i get  keys  ,but me do not need keys ,me need  value(stage) which has  name.Ok i thought  if  i had  key i would can use it for open list.For e.x  stages.key return stage dict  ,but it does not work, it return error :)

Comment: But something looks wrong there, stages and stage need to be wrapped in ' '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view, considering

```
context = {
        'stages':'...'
        }
```

In templates

```
{{stages.0.stage.name}}
```